# Get multiple columns by applying 2 conditions on one column from csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to get data from CSV file by applying two conditions on the same column.

For example, If CSV file contains columns like date, value, product. Then, I need to get all 3 data between sdate(Provided by a user) and edate(Provided by a user).

```
df.loc[(df['Date'] == sdate) & (df['Date'] == edate)]
```

Here, sdate and edate are variable name and Date is column name in csv file.

Comment: what error are you getting??? your syntax is correct

Comment: No, it shows all data instead of a range of data that i need

Comment: `df.loc[(df['Date'] >= sdate) & (df['Date'] <= edate)]`

Comment: Please give examples for `sdate` and `edate` and also a small sample for `df`.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in code that data are read from CSV file and for applying conditions on same column inner for loop is used. This will extract data with all rows according to condition given.

```
with open(fName,'rt') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
    print(data)
    df = pd.read_csv(fName)
    print(df.loc[(df['Date'] == sdate)])
    for x in df['Date']:
    if (x<sdate) & (x>edate):
    df1 = df(x)
    print(df1)
```